# How to get percent value from property style element not pixel one using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want take percent value property element with Jquery but I can't do it.
My elements are:

```
<tr id="rows">
    <td style="right:0%;"></td>
    <td style="right:20%;"></td>
    <td style="right:40%;"></td>
    <td style="right:60%;"></td>
    <td style="right:80%;"></td>
</tr>
```

I want get right value with percent sign.
I'v used below method but returned value was pixel value:

```
$('#rows td').last().css('right');
```

Console show me this `772px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look:

```
var c = $('#rows td').last().get(0);
console.log( c.style.right );
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93CxA/

Comment: +1 for using native DOM access to the attributes. I believe this is the best solution

Comment: @koala_dev it's ok koalaman , i've got my 2 upvotes :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the value directly using jQuery, but in your case a solution could be to parse your style attribute using a regex to match the number inside the string

```
var percentValue = $('#rows td').last().attr('style').match(/\d+/)+'%';
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM4gQ/1/)**

Comment: @money, I believe Cherniv produced a better solution with his approach, you should consider marking his as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var right = ( 100 * parseFloat($('#rows td').css('right')) / parseFloat($('#rows td').parent().css('right')) ) + '%';
```

Comment: Didn't see abc123's comment ...